# Use solrj to get the date difference of 8 hours

Tags: java, solr, solrj, solr6

**There's a data in my solr:** [Using the Solr Administration User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlrmP.jpg), the modifyTime is "2016-04-20T13:58:35.805Z".

**Using solrj:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZIU5.jpg), the modifyTime is "Wed Apr 20 21:58:35 CST 2016".

I'm using solr6. Why?

Comment: It's because you have different time zones on both machines(machine that hosts Solr and local machine), your local machine uses CST as a default time zone, can you please check the default time zone on Solr machine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modifyTime data format coming from Solr Administration User Interface is UTC, you can understand it by the Z at the end of datetime string, indicating that this string representation of the date is in UTC.

```
2016-04-20T13:58:35.805Z
```

On the other hand, modifyTime coming from data format is CST – <s>Central</s> **China** Standard Time, which in your case it seems to be + 8 hours.

```
Wed Apr 20 21:58:35 CST 2016
```

This happens because of a Java annoying and bad feature where the java.util.Date has no time zone yet it's toString method applies the JVM's current default time zone.

```
java.util.Date date = ( java.util.Date ) doc.getFieldValue("modifyTime");
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.UTC );
String output = dateTimeUtc.toString();
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @BasilBourque for the suggestion on the meaning of CST (Time Zone Abbreviation)

Comment: I suspect the zone is China Standard Time, not Central.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque, you're right, I was just curious to understand why CST had so many hours :)

Answer (score 1):

## China Standard Time (CST)

The [answer by Alfredo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38591584/642706) is correct but for one assumption. That answer mentions Central Standard Time, but that zone is *behind* UTC (7 or 6 hours) while the data in the Question is *ahead* of UTC. So I presume `CST` here refers to [China Standard Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cst-china) which is 8 ahead of UTC.

This confusion shows why we should never use these 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `CST`. They are not true time zones, not standardized, and are not even unique (as we see here). Instead use [proper tz/IANA time zones](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the form of `continent/region`.

## java.time

The problem is the use of the old date-time classes. These poorly designed and notoriously troublesome classes have been supplanted in Java 8 and later by the java.time framework.

That string should be directly parsed by [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) to get a value in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-04-20T13:58:35.805Z" );
```

Call [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) to get the same kind of string back, formatted according to the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

Apply a time zone to see the same moment through the lens of a particular locality’s [wall-clock time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time). Apply a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

For the example of `America/Montreal` the wall-clock time is four hours behind UTC, so the hour is `09` instead of `13`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```

> 2016-04-20T09:58:35.805-04:00[America/Montreal]

Both the `Instant` and the `ZonedDateTime` represent the same simultaneous point on the timeline.

Comment: Thank you!What's the best solution when I use solrj? I have to manually change the result every time.I want to change the result of solrj.For example, let it return DateTime or CST

Comment: My understanding of date, time, and computer science has just skyrocketed